# Is there any difference between the following two in terms of grammar or context?

Tags: numbers

Is there any difference between the following two in terms of grammar or context:

> *Richard St. John, in his lecture, pointed out some factors in life which lead people to success. He said he conducted* ***500*** *interviews over a period of* ***7*** *years and came to the conclusion that the following* ***8*** *factors make people successful*...

and,

> *Richard St. John, in his lecture, pointed out some factors in life which lead people to success. He said he conducted* ***five-hundred*** *interviews over a period of* ***seven*** *years and came to the conclusion that the following* ***eight*** *factors make people successful*...

If there is, When to use which format?

Comment: It's usual to write out small numbers as a word, but use figures for large numbers. If you do write 'five hundred', it isn't hyphenated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Five hundred" should not have a hyphen. Generally, small whole numbers should be written out ("seven", "eight"). For "five hundred", the numeral form is better ("500").
Here is a link to a discussion of the subject:
[Scribendi "When to spell out numbers"](https://www.scribendi.com/advice/when_to_spell_out_numbers_in_writing.en.html)